# Magento 2: Customer Import CSV "The file was not uploaded."

Tags: magento2, customer, import

I'm getting an unusual error on my server. It's working fine in Local & on a server able to Import Product CSV.

For Customer only I'm getting this error. I have tried with my local WAMP Customer CSV, still same error.

[image]

Comment: any update on this issue @Ankit?

Comment: Nope still have issue on Server don't know why?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing too much detail about the `.csv` itself. The likely reason will be the Maximum upload size on your `php.ini` settings. By default it's normally `2mb` on earlier versions of PHP.

Find this line on the `php.ini` file which looks like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir ="c:/wamp/tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Whereas you may change the "upload_max_filesize" to whichever you need.

Additionally you may need to update:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
```

Make sure you restart your Webserver to make the new settings appear.